# oracle query between two dates with hours

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

This is my current oracle table:

- DATE = date
- HOUR = number
- RUN_DURATION = number

[image]

I need a query to get RUN_DURATION between two dates **with hours** like

`Select * from Datatable where DATE BETWEEN to_date('myStartDate', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + HOURS? and to_date('myEndDate', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + HOURS?`

*For example all data between 30.10.14 11:00:00 and 30.10.14 15:00:00*

I stuck to get the hours to the dates. I tried to add the hours into myStartDate but this will be ignored for the start date because of `BETWEEN`.
I know `BETWEEN` shouldn't be used for dates but I can't try other opportunities because I don't know how to get `DATE` and `HOUR` together...
Thanks!

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with using `BETWEEN` with dates. Are you trying to add the `HOUR` column to the `DATE` column? Its very unclear.

Comment: The problem here is separating the dates from the hours. You'll have to combine them again to do the query, using something like (date + hour/24)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I need for example all data for date between 10.08.15 08:00 and 11.08.15 10:00

Comment: The dates in your example have no correlation to your screenshot. Please edit your question and explain what you would expect from the sample rows shown in your question.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid the table has millions entries and some other fields. I made a query and updated the screenshot, hope now that it is clear. For example I need all data between 30.10.14 11:00:00 and 30.10.14 15:00:00, result should be entries with HOUR 12, 13 and 14

Comment: If you want data between those dates... _what rows in your example would you expect to return?_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A **DATE** has both date and time elements. To add hours to date, you just need to do some mathematics.

For example,

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT SYSDATE, SYSDATE + 1/24 FROM dual;

SYSDATE             SYSDATE+1/24
------------------- -------------------
2015-08-14 15:02:59 2015-08-14 16:02:59
```

Adds 1 hour to sysdate. So, if you have a column of date data type, just add **number of hours to be added divided by 24** because you add **number of days** to a date. So, you just need to first convert the number of hours into date as `hours/24`.

Answer (score 10):

Well, you can add hour to your field date this way

```
select "DATE" + (hour / 24) from <yourTable>
```

this will give you ( from your first sample, may be different based on your format)

```
August, 14 2015 10:00:00 
August, 14 2015 08:00:00
```

Based on that, you can do any between, select that you need.

In your case

```
where "DATE" + (hour / 24 )
```

which would make

```
Select * 
from Datatable 
where "DATE" + (hour / 24 )
 BETWEEN to_date('30/10/2014 11:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  and            
         to_date('30/10/2014 15:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d9e0/5)

(By the way, don't use reserved keywords for column name, but I guess this is just a sample).

Comment: Thanks, works great. Thanks for the hint with the reserved keywords, it's a given table so I can't change the name. Made me some frustration with my c# query until someone told me to use `\"DATE\"` for the field

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add `min` to `date` you can use `interval`.

```
select sysdate, sysdate + interval '1' hour from dual
```

So,

```
Select * 
from Datatable 
where 
DATE BETWEEN myStartDate + interval to_char(HOURS) hour 
and myEndDate + interval to_char(HOURS) hour
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE date BETWEEN start_date +  NUMTODSINTERVAL( hour, 'HOUR' ) AND end_date +  NUMTODSINTERVAL( hour, 'HOUR' )
```